# Is there a way to make an image larger without losing quality?

Tags: resize, image-quality, image-format

What's the best way to take the attached 'CobraJet' 72 dpi image and prepare it for inclusion in a printed poster?

1) I tried finding similar fonts

2) I tried blowing image up and blurring it

3) I don't have illustrator (just PS CS6)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Best is not defined, you only have bad and even worse approaches. DPI says nothing, at what size in the 300 dpi document do you want it?

Comment: Best? Find a bigger file, period. Second best is to place it *very small*, third option is to not put in on your poster. This is beyond what software can do, and if this is what you have there is no "best way" that can make it look good.

Comment: Can't be done. To enlarge effectively, you'd need to recreate at a higher PPI.

Comment: Searching [does provide larger images](http://cdn3.volusion.com/dafgx.xaceu/v/vspfiles/photos/1641-2.jpg?1393595921) which would be great reference for recreating.

Comment: here you are a bigger version of the logo. http://cdn3.volusion.com/dafgx.xaceu/v/vspfiles/photos/1641-2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to resize the image without losing a lot of quality in the image. You can:

Try creating the logo in photoshop. Trace with the pen tool. Then follow this tutorial to get a chrome effect. http://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/chrome/chrome.htm or search for other tutorials.

The other way is to up-scale the image you have but probably won't give you the desired results. If only we had CSI technology.

One of the ways to upscale and an image in Photoshop is to use the 10% trick.

First go to image - image size then follow these steps:

1. Set the 'Resample Image' option to 'Bicubic Smoother'
2. Click 'Resample Image' off (So its not checked)
3. Change the resolution to your needs (Usually you want to be between 240 and 300 pixels/inch for print.)
4. Click 'Resample Image' back on
5. Change your Inches to Percent and increase your width and height with 10 percent increments. ('110%' click OK, '110%' click OK, '110% click OK, ...and so on)
   This could be kind of tedious so create an action for this last step.

Comment: tried the 110% trick .. didn't get good results..

Comment: is there a good pen tool tutorial you can recommend?

Comment: @Justin Levy - Try this for Bezier pen tool practice: http://bezier.method.ac/.